# How can I draw a right angle with MetaPost?

Tags: metapost, angle

I want to use MetaPost to draw a right angle `BAC`. `A = (20,30)`, `B = (0,0)`, the top of the angle is point `A`.

How can I compute the coordinate of point `C`?

[image: The Right Angle]

Comment: Angle's top is on which point?

Comment: It is point `A`.

Comment: since the right angle `B` is at origin, you can have `C` at (-20,30) or (20,-30) based on `A`'s coordinate.

Comment: Oops, I made a terrible typo. In fact, I want to draw right angle `BAC`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `dotprod`:

```
u:=1mm;
beginfig(1);
z0=origin;
z1=(20u,30u);
y2=y0;
(z1-z0) dotprod (z2-z1)=0;
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\drawAngle(#1)(#2){%
\psnode(#1){A}{A}\psnode(#2){B}{B}
\psnode(!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{B}
       A.y B.y sub A.x add A.x B.x sub neg A.y add ){C}{C}
\psline(B)(A)(C)
\psarc(A){1}{!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{B}
  B.y A.y sub B.x A.x sub atan}{!B.y A.y sub B.x A.x sub atan 90 add}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(4,3)
\drawAngle(1,2)(2,-2)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\drawAngle(4,-1)(2,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use MetaPost only.

Comment: should not be difficult to write \drawAngle in Metapost. You can use B.x also in MP.

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6.6,3)
\psset{PointSymbol=none}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={45,-135}](2,3){A}(0,0){B}
\pstRotation[RotAngle=90,PointName=none]{A}{B}
\pnode(A|B){B''}
\pstInterLL{A}{B'}{B}{B''}{C}
\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
\pstRightAngle{B}{A}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Descriptions:

- `\psset{PointSymbol=none}` to turn the dots off.
- `\pstGeonode[PosAngle={45,-135}](2,3){A}(0,0){B}` to specify the point `A` and `B`.
- `\pstRotation[RotAngle=90,PointName=none]{A}{B}` to rotate point `B` 90 degrees about `A`, the new point is implicitly named as `B'`.
- `\pnode(A|B){B''}` to define an auxiliary point `B''` whose coordinate is `(A.x,B.y)`.
- `\pstInterLL{A}{B'}{B}{B''}{C}` to find the intersection point `C` between the lines `AB'` and `BB''`.
- `\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)` to draw the triangle `ABC`.
- `\pstRightAngle{B}{A}{C}` to attach the L-shape right angle mark.

Comment: I'm using MetaPost, but it's really a good tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you understand that there are infinite point that are perpindicular to AB. So actually you are looking for a line. To find it, just assume the vector AB with coordinates `BA=(20-0,30-0)=(20,30)=a` and vector `BC=(x-0, y-0)=(x,y)=b`.

To find vector coordinates you just apply `(xend-xstart, yend-ystart)`. The requirement you have is that `a` and `b` must be perpendicular. In vector analysis, this means that the dot product must be zero, ie

```
a.b=0-> 
(20,30).(x,y)=0->20x+30y=0->
y=-(2/3)x
```

So choose an `x` apply the previous line equation and you'll get your `y`.

[image]

Edit: I saw you changed your question. In that way you will have a new line with same slope but with different intercept. So your line will be something like

`y=ux+w`

with `u` being the same slope, `u=-2/3`, that is. On the same time it should pass from point `A` so this point has to be a solution of the line. So replacing `A`'s coordinates in line equation you'll get

```
30=-(2/3)20+b->
...->
b=130/3
```

So your new line is

```
y=-(2/3)x+130/3
```

Again for every `x` you'll get a `y`.

Comment: Can I write a MetaPost macro to solve it?